# Overwrite Jquery error message when click twice on submit button

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I am using `showErrors` in jquery form validation to display error message on the top of the form. At a time I want display one error message. In my form `name,email,url and comment` four fields available. If user directly clicks on submit button without entering any data than it is displaying error for `name` field but when user focus on `email` fields than it overwrite error message for `name` and `email` both.

Jquery :-

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").validate({
    messages: {
         name: "Please specify your name.",
         email: {
           required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
           email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com."
         },
         url: "A valid URL, please.",
         comment: "Please enter your comment."
       },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if(errorList.length) {
                $("span").html(errorList[0].message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Here is fiddle :- http://jsfiddle.net/roop1886/q64VE/

Comment: You're only displaying `errorList[0]`, so it can only display one error.

Comment: yes i want display one error message at a time.

Comment: When you're in a field and it's validating as you type, `errorList` only contains that field's error.

Comment: See, if user click on submit button than it is displaying error for `name` it is correct but if user focus on `email` field and again click on submit button than it should display error message for `name`. Now it is overwrite error message for name and email .

Comment: That's what it does for me. When I click on submit, it always shows the name error. While I'm typing in the email or comment field, it shows the error for that field.

Comment: Thanks Barmar for your time. Is there any solution???

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31168/discussion-between-roopendra-and-barmar)

Comment: For what? It's doing what you say it should.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution  :- I have added  `focusInvalid: false,` suggested by @Barmar in `$("form").validate()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").validate({
   focusInvalid: false,
    messages: {
         name: "Please specify your name.",
         email: {
           required: "We need your email address to contact you.",
           email: "Your email address must be in the format of name@domain.com."
         },
         url: "A valid URL, please.",
         comment: "Please enter your comment."
       },
    showErrors: function(errorMap, errorList) {
            if(errorList.length) {
                $("span").html(errorList[0].message);
            }
        }
    });
});
```